# Bash: what is the most efficient way to handle I/O?

Tags: bash, unix, io

I have a bash script which does a lot of string manipulations. As I know, reading from a file is slow. So instead of doing it every time I need its contents, I read the whole file at the beginning of the script

```sh
readarray -t lines < "$filename"
```

But every time I need to feed the lines to a program which accepts input (e.g., `awk`, `cut`, `grep`), I anyway have to print them and create a pipeline. Here's an example which finds the first line which contains a colon in a file

```sh
line=$(printf -- '%s\n' "${lines[@]}" | grep -n -m 1 :)
```

So I started wondering, didn't I just make it slower by making additional calls to `echo` and creating a pipeline? What's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: It highly depends on the file size and what all you want to do with the data. It may be better to feed the file directly into tools like `grep`, `awk` etc. Unless the file is too big for your available memory, it will probably get cached by your OS, so the second access will be much faster. You should [edit] your question and show a better example that shows what "*lot of string manipulations*" you want to do based on the file. With `line=$(grep -n -m 1 : "$filename")`, `grep` can immediately stop reading the file when it has found a match while `readarray` will always read the whole file.

Comment: I suggest not to try such optimizations unless you have found a real performance problem. Otherwise it is more important to have code that is clear and easy to understand.

Comment: @kenticent : You worry about the time to process a **file**, but don't mind spawing child processes (grep, awk, ....) for your task? If you really fear performance problems, I would try to implement everything in a single process, if possible. Depending on what exactly you are going to do, it may mean that you have to give up bash for something else - awk, Perl, Ruby, Python, or whatever.

Comment: Do you need to slurp the `$filename` into an array? Do you manipulate lines individually? If you just want the contents of the file, use `contents=$(< "$filename")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bash-specific `<<<` operator to pipe variables into commands without `echo`/`printf`-ing them:

```
λ printf "test\nline\n" > file
λ cat file
test
line
λ readarray -t lines < file
λ wc -c <<< "${lines[0]}"
5
λ printf "%s" "${lines[0]}"
test
```

Also instead of reading the file into a variable you could consume it directly with something like this assuming you dont need all the contents at once:

```
while read -r line; do
    grep -n -m1 ':' <<< "$line" && {
        echo "Got colon"
        break
    }
done < filename
```

Comment: Will it work with `grep`? Because in the example I've provided we need to previously format the lines so each element of the array will contain a newline in the end

Comment: When reading lines using `while read -r line`, they're broken up at newlines by default.

Comment: Depending on the exact situation, using `<<<` may well be slower than just reading from the file, because (at least as I understand it) the way `<<<` is implemented is that bash writes the string into a file, and then lets the command read from that file... which is clearly going to be slower than just reading from an already-existing file without having to write anything first. (Mind you, creating a subprocess to run `echo` or `printf` will generally be even slower.)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to see which is faster, you can try to use `time`:

```
time readarray -t lines < "$filename"

time line=$(printf -- '%s\n' "${lines[@]}" | grep -n -m 1 :)
```

That will give you the time taken in milliseconds, and will let you see which one is faster.